# Realistic Friction Rigid Bodies

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to do a "satisfying" video with physics and don't really know much about them. My problem is I can't figure out the right settings to make it look realistic.

Perhaps it is something to do with friction? It seems that if I change the numbers it doesn't really affect the results. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks!

- WC

[Blender File Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bzyyIrPAwxfsoAxgetbkoVYRn82kVMk7/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've increased the *Mass* (0.5) and *Bouciness* (1,2) of the balls, and also put a circle (*Type > Passive, Shape > Mesh*) on the front and back so that the balls don't jump out, and it seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Did you come up with those numbers by just playing around with it?

Comment: I never would have thought to change the bounciness

Comment: yes just testing the parameters, also maybe switch the balls from sphere to mesh